# Wrong cursor in SimpleCursorTreeAdapter's getChildCursor()

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm using `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` for `ExpandableListView`. The problem is once groupCursor is utilised, then in`getChildCursor(Cursor groupCursor)`groupCursor is returning unexpected columns, the columns in `groupCursor` are **replaced** with **Child Cursor's columns**.

I am unable to trace why the group cursor column's are replaced with child column's. And is it a good way to use `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` to bind database with `ExpandableListView`.

I am trying different ways from past 3 days in CursorTreeAdapter and SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.

Please find the below screenshots for more detailed explanation.

**Constructor initialized correctly with cursor having 3 columns**

[image]

**In getChidrenCount(), returning correct results upto some iterations.You can see the column's in debug are still 3**

[image]

**After some iterations,the column values are changed. This is where the total problem is..**

[image]

Suggest me the Best possible solutions.

Thanks & Regards,
Sha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doono whats's the problem, but i resolved the issue by implementing my own Custom Adapter.